# How can I have all my powershell scripts run without permissions issues?

Tags: powershell, permissions, windows-10

I've never had to configure this on Windows 10. My Powershell scripts keep giving me an issue in the ISE regarding execution policy (even though I changed the registry key at Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell to unrestricted and about needing to run as administrator even though I'm logged in as a local admin. I can't even run stop-service because of this.

How can I configure this machine to never have Powershell permissions issues again? Do I need to reimage it with a different OS?

Windows 10 pro 64 bit and Powershell 5.1.17134.858

Comment: Instead of modifying the registry try to set the execution policy in PowerShell with the command `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`... Is the Computer part of a domain. Maybe Group Policy overrides the setting: _Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows PowerShell_

Comment: Hey Mike, it's a home computer that isn't in a domain. I set the registry with Powershell and then verified the key in regedit. Idk about the group policy as I can't remember if I imaged it or if it came imaged (it was used) so I'll verify there is no residual group policy applied.

What I don't understand is why an admin account would have any restrictions ever?

Comment: Hi Bbb, what result do you get when you run `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` ? Maybe there is also a HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry setting you can check/modify. Or try using the `-Scope` parameter in the `Set-ExecutionPolicy` command. Microsoft has a good documentation about Execution Policies. Maybe it will help you to narrow down the problem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-6

Comment: @Mike 
        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine    Unrestricted

What do you think?

Comment: @Mike this is quite odd I think?

PS C:\Users\Elite 8300> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope UserPolicy Unrestricted
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Cannot set execution policy. Execution policies at the MachinePolicy or UserPolicy scopes must
be set through Group Policy.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope UserPolicy Unrestricted
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CantSetGroupPolicy,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand

Comment: I tried different ways to reproduce this issue on my machine, but no luck, it works every time.  Instead of using _UserPolicy_ as Scope you have to use _CurrentUser_ like this `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser` ... You can also check your Powerhell settings in W10. **Settings - For Developers** scroll down and looking for PowerShell. Maybe you have to modify something.